# Curl command showing as undefined with token in swagger UI.?

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui

I am integrating the swagger UI in my project.  I need to pass the token to make a request.

```
const mytoken = "heareismytoken";

const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "/swagger/v2/swagger.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    requestInterceptor: function (req) {
        var key = mytoken;

        if (key && key.trim() !== "") {
            req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + key;
            console.log('Authorized from authKey');
        }
    },
    presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout",
});
```

With the above code I am getting the successful response but the problem is curl command is showing as undefined like below image[image]

If I removed the following part of code

```
    /* 
    requestInterceptor: function (req) {
        var key = mytoken;

        if (key && key.trim() !== "") {
            req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + key;
            console.log('Authorized from authKey');
        }
    }, */
```

the curl command is showing but the response is throwing the authentication error.

I don't know exactly where I am missing it. How to the show both CURL command and the Response.?

Comment: Can you also post the code where `mytoken` is defined?

Comment: @Helen I added the token on top after that I am calling the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation of Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#network):

> requestInterceptor:
>
> `Function=(a => a)`. MUST be a function. Function to intercept remote definition, "Try it out", and OAuth 2.0 requests. Accepts one argument requestInterceptor(request) **and must return the modified request**, or a Promise that resolves to the modified request.

In provided code **return statement is missing**. Correct code will be:

```
requestInterceptor: function (req) {
    var key = mytoken;

    if (key && key.trim() !== "") {
        req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + key;
        console.log('Authorized from authKey');
    }
    return req; // <--- This line was added
}
```